# How to configure Visual Studio Code to use Anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I tried to `import numpy`  but got a `no module named numpy` this error only appears to occur in VS code, because I tried `import numpy` on `spyder` and spyder did not return any error, so that led me to believe my configuration for my python interpreter was was wrong.

things I've tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda
- checking if `numpy` and `matplotlib` was installed on my computer already, which it was
- uninstalling and reinstalling `numpy` and `matplotlib` just in case.
- My `anaconda3` is located in
  `/Users/MacBook/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`.
- Path in my
  `.bash_profile`: `export PATH="/Users/MacBook/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`
- The current python
  interpreter on VS code is `Python 3.8.8 (base: conda)`.     my python
  version is 3.8.2 and `numpy` is version `1.20.1  py38hd6e1bb9_0`

Screenshot of all interpreter on VS code
[image]

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Has your question been resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a new **integrated terminal** in VS Code and run

```
source activate base
```

Conda environment needs to be activated after selecting it as python interpreter, then install required module in it.